# Find the coordinates of the vertices of an equilateral triangle contained in a circle of radius 1, with one of the vertices $cis (\pi/2)$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

> Find the coordinates of the vertices of an equilateral triangle
>   contained in a circle of radius 1, with one of the vertices $cis
>  (\pi/2)$

[image]

In this case, A = $cis (\pi/2)$.

I need to figure out C and B.

I suspect that there is some rotation associated with this, such that the angle of B is the angle of A + $\pi/2$ + something. Just by looking at it, this something looks like it could be 30 degrees, but I am not sure.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would rotate it $\pi / 2$ degrees to the right, so that the top vertex is instead at $0$. Assume that the new triangle is $\Delta A'B'C'$

Then, we know that the angle $C'A'B' = \pi/3$.

From here, considering this as vectors, we get that with $O$ being the origin, $OB' = OA' + A'B'$. This should give us the coordinates of $B'$.

Convert this to $r*cis(\theta)$ form, and add $\pi/2$ to get back to the original coordinates. Note that point $C$ has the same radius as point $B$

Assuming that the radian measure for $B = \theta$, for $C$, it is $-\theta + \pi$

EDIT: Solving the problem

After the rotation, $OA' = <1,0>$. Also, $A'B'$ is thirty degrees up from the x-axis (just draw this to understand).

So, Vector $A'B' = <r*\cos(180-30), r*\sin(180-30)>$.

Using the law of cosines, we can find that $r = \sqrt{3}$

Now, we have the equation $OB' = <1,0> + <\sqrt{3}*\cos(180-30), \sqrt{3}*\sin(180-30)>$

Which gives us $OB' = <1 + \sqrt{3}*\cos(150), \sqrt{3}*\sin(150)>$

Converting into $r*cis(\theta)$ form (the radius is $1$ because it's on the unit circle, we find that the vector is $1*cis(\tan^{-1}{\frac{\sqrt{3}*\sin(150)}{1 + \sqrt{3}*\cos(150)}}+180)$ (note that the $+180$ is to get it into the third quadrant, as $\arctan$ returns values in the first and fourth quadrant).

Now, this simplifies down very nicely to $B' = cis(120)$. Moving it $90$ to the left, we get $B = cis(210)$, and $C = cis(330)$. Convert these to Cartesian if you want to.

Comment: I am trying to do $0A'+A'B'$. I know that $|0A'|=|A'B'|=1$. I am not very good with vectors, do I just add the magnitudes? Or do I convert both to the complex form and then add the vectors?

Comment: Go to complex $a + bi$ form, add them, then convert back to $r*cis(\theta)$

Comment: I tried converting those points to the complex form and I got $0A'(1;0),0B'(x;yi),A'B'(1+|x|;yi)$. Here |x| is the absolute value of x, because x is negative. So I tried to solve $x+yi = (1+1+|x|)+(0+yi) \Leftrightarrow x = 2+|x| \Leftrightarrow 2x = 2 \Leftrightarrow x = 1$. But this can't be right. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Not sure why you're using variables; You can get the coordinates of point $B'$ using polar form of complex numbers. I'll add my process to the answer.

Comment: Please do so...

Comment: Ok I'm starting to understand, could explain how you used the law of cosines? What triangle did you consider?

Comment: And what is the angle at B'0A'?

Comment: $120$; you know this because it's an isosceles triangle, and $OA'B' = OB'A' = 30$.

Comment: Riight, I understand now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First note that since ABC is a equilateral triangle, its vertices makes equal angles with the origin. So the angles AOB, BOC and COA are all $\dfrac{2\pi}{3}$. Now the vertex $A$ makes an angle of $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ with the real axis, so $A$ is the point $cis(\frac{\pi}{2})$. If $A$ is rotated further by an angle of $\dfrac{2\pi}{3}$ you will reach $B$ which is the point $cis(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{2\pi}{3})=cis(\frac{7\pi}{6})$. Further rotation of $B$ by an angle of $\dfrac{2\pi}{3}$ will take you to point $C$ which is $cis(\frac{7\pi}{6}+\frac{2\pi}{3})=cis(\frac{11\pi}{6})$.

Comment: Why does rotating A by 60 degrees make it equal to point B?

Comment: $A$ is rotated by an angle of $\frac{2\pi}{3}=120$ degrees to reach $B$.